Table contents slightly offset towards the top
So I am trying to create a table. As you can see, the text is ever so slightly offset towards the top. How do I fix this?
Here is the code:
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{table}[htbp]
    \centering
    \caption{My Table}
    \vspace*{-2mm}
    \begin{tabular}{>{\centering}m{3cm}|ccc|ccc}
        \hline
        \multirow{2}{*}{Model} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Transfer learning} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{End-to-end learning} \\
        \cline{2-7}
        & Accuracy & Precision & Recall & Accuracy & Precision & Recall \\
        \hline
        Baseline (non-FSL) & Row 1 & Row 1 & Row 1 & Row 1 & Row 1 & Row 1 \\
        Baseline & Row 2 & Row 2 & Row 2 & Row 2 & Row 2 & Row 2 \\
        ProtoNet & Row 3 & Row 3 & Row 3 & Row 3 & Row 3 & Row 3 \\
        MatchingNet & Row 4 & Row 4 & Row 4 & Row 4 & Row 4 & Row 4 \\
        Reptile & Row 5 & Row 5 & Row 5 & Row 5 & Row 5 & Row 5 \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}



please provide a complete example that produces the problem. What do you mean by offset here? the code fragment has a negative space of -2mm which moves everything up but that can't be run as you only have posted a fragment and the image does not show any context to see the vertical position of the table. So it is not clear what the issue is?

in general beware m columns, they have their uses but they lose baseline alignment, I would use p for the first column.

Hi Nico, a quick hack would be to add something like \rule{0pt}{2.2ex} before "Accuracy" (and anywhere else you want it). That creates a box that will poke up a bit above the "A", so will create a bit more padding around the text in your table (which I think is what you're after), but it has zero width so you won't actually see it.

Thank you guys for the feedback!

You could change the \arraystretch or use booktabs:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[table]{
  position=above, aboveskip=1mm,
  }

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]
    \centering\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
    \caption{My Table}
    \begin{tabular}{>{\centering}p{3cm}|ccc|ccc}
        \hline
        \multirow{2}{*}{Model} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Transfer learning} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{End-to-end learning} \\
        \cline{2-7}
        & Accuracy & Precision & Recall & Accuracy & Precision & Recall \\
        \hline
        Baseline (non-FSL) & Row 1 & Row 1 & Row 1 & Row 1 & Row 1 & Row 1 \\
        Baseline & Row 2 & Row 2 & Row 2 & Row 2 & Row 2 & Row 2 \\
        ProtoNet & Row 3 & Row 3 & Row 3 & Row 3 & Row 3 & Row 3 \\
        MatchingNet & Row 4 & Row 4 & Row 4 & Row 4 & Row 4 & Row 4 \\
        Reptile & Row 5 & Row 5 & Row 5 & Row 5 & Row 5 & Row 5 \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\begin{table}[htbp]
    \centering
    \caption{My Table}
    \begin{tabular}{lcccccc}% first column left align as egreg said
        \toprule
         & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Transfer learning} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{End-to-end learning} \\
        \cmidrule(lr){2-4}\cmidrule(lr){5-7}
        Model & Accuracy & Precision & Recall & Accuracy & Precision & Recall \\
        \midrule
        Baseline (non-FSL) & Row 1 & Row 1 & Row 1 & Row 1 & Row 1 & Row 1 \\
        Baseline & Row 2 & Row 2 & Row 2 & Row 2 & Row 2 & Row 2 \\
        ProtoNet & Row 3 & Row 3 & Row 3 & Row 3 & Row 3 & Row 3 \\
        MatchingNet & Row 4 & Row 4 & Row 4 & Row 4 & Row 4 & Row 4 \\
        Reptile & Row 5 & Row 5 & Row 5 & Row 5 & Row 5 & Row 5 \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}



I would recommend not to use m for that purpose: 3cm is pure guessing and isn't necessary at all. Also, the first column should be left-aligned. Not to mention \multirow that I consider ruining the shape of the table: the main headers should be aligned to each other.

@egreg I didn't use m, 3cm was in the OP's MWE

I see, but p is bad the same. ;-)

@egreg I followed David's comment

@egreg better now?

“Model” should be in the top row, in my opinion. I already upvoted, though. :-)

@egreg I was undecided on where to put it. It would go at the top according to the meaning but aesthetically I like it at the bottom, otherwise there would be too much empty space below

I appreciate your help!!

@nico Thank you!
